# How to translate this handwritten sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, handwriting, kurrent

I need help translating this sentence.

> Sie sehen daß noch nicht alles was den Auszeichnungen herauszulesen
>   vor.

My problems here are that I cannot understand the use of "*daß*" (shouldn't be the verb be at the end?) and the "*zu*" in "*herauszulesen*", which seems to be the verb in the subordinate clause.

This is the first line of an old letter (1931) which refers to "characterizations" (*Auszeichnungen*?) obtained in a previous one.

I transcribed the above sentence from the following hand-written letter, so it may be something is not completely  correct.

[image]

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I modified the question, adding the hand-written source for the text. I deleted tatsachlich and Fittingschen but the meaning should be the same.

Comment: Sie sehen[,] daß tatsächlich noch nicht alles aus den Fittingschen Aufzeichnungen herauszulesen war (mißverstanden habe übrigens mehr ich als Fitting) -- So I think it is "Aufzeichnungen", not "Auszeichnungen" (but that does not matter so much), and "aus" not "was", and that way it makes sense

Comment: Probably: "übrigens mehr ich als"

Comment: The next fragment is "Es scheint mir nicht so schwer" and feels like an ironic comment to our attempts at deciphering the text ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, "aus" instead of "was" should make sense. I didn't think of it because they put a line on the "u"s to make a difference with the "n"s, but she probably forgotten it in the rush.
...and the other parts of the letter are even more ironic!

Comment: Brilliant, @HagenvonEitzen.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen please transfer your comment to a proper answer.

Comment: To all the close-voters: Please notice that deciphering old hand-writings is on-topic (see: Sind Fragen über die Entschlüsselung von Schriften (auch Handschriften) on-topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decyphering Sütterlin is certainly a difficult task for us today, and there seem to be many ambiguous interpretations of which letters those really were. This is what I read (with additional help by the OP) from the image:

> Sie sehen[,] daß tatsächlich noch nicht *alles* aus den Fittingschen Aufzeichnungen herauszulesen war (*miß*verstanden habe übrigens mehr *ich* als Fitting). Es scheint mir nicht so schwer, die [...]

or translated something like

> You see that indeed not yet everything could be read from Fitting's notes (by the way, I misunderstood more than Fitting did). To me it does not seem that difficult to [...]

So for one, I guess it is "Aufzeichnungen" ("written notes") instead of "Auszeichnungen". But more importantly, my guess fo rthe last word of the first line is "aus" istead of "was". It seems that the author only *sometimes* put a clarifying bar over "u" (e.g., in "Aufzeichnungen" only for the second "u"; which makes sense as in that place - between two "n" - we'd otherwise really just have a long streak of zig-zag lines), and without that one can indeed easily mistake "aus" for something like "was".